# Windows Socket API: WSASendTo vs. WSASendMsg vs. TransmitPackets?

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, winsock, winsock2

I don't understand the main difference between `WSASendTo`, `WSASendMsg`, and `TransmitPackets` for sending in-memory buffers:

- They all allow buffer gathering
- All of them allow overlapped (asynchronous) operation
- `WSASendTo` and `TransmitPackets` both allow stream sockets (`WSASendMsg` doesn't seem to)

Obviously there are some minor functionality difference (for example, only `WSASendMsg` can send control information), but I'm not talking about those, since there is no choice to be made there.
For the most part, they all seem the same, and I imagine one of them is used by the rest.

What I'm wondering is, *if I'm just sending data from an in-memory buffer to a stream or datagram socket*, how do I choose which one to use?

Is any of them faster/better? Or, do they differ in any aspects such as (but not limited to):

- Packet efficiency?
- How big the buffers can be?
- How big their queue sizes are?
- Blocking vs. error behavior when the queue is full?
- Cache behavior? (note that I'm *not* talking about sending files, just memory buffers)
- Or anything else?

Comment: `WSASendTo()` and `WSASendMsg()` both transmit data into the socket send buffer. What happens after that is entirely up to the transport layer and doesn't change.

Comment: @EJP: Thanks. That begs the questions: (1) What's the difference between the first two, then? (2) In what sense is it not comparable? Can't I substitute them for each other?

Comment: The difference between the first two is the API itself, as you have already noted. `TransmitPackets()` is unknown to me but it has some interaction with the OS elements you mentioned, all documented.

Comment: @EJP: I'll phrase it another way. If I'm sending datagrams, and I'm not sending control information, are they different at all?

Comment: Once you get past the API and start moving data they are exactly the same. I thought I had already said that. Oh wait, I did.

Comment: @EJP: OK, well I didn't sure what "is up to the transport layer" meant. I thought it might include "the transport layer may decide to treat them differently, and we don't know".